# Android - difference between show Alert dialog on service directly and by activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Since I read showing Alert Dialog on Service may damage on other program , I want to know is there difference between showing Alert Dialog directly like this:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        alertDialog.show();
```

And showing through specific activity?

I want something like communication application's popup (e.g. Line Messenger,..) 
which of ways do you recommend?

Comment: a `android.app.Notification` ?

Comment: @pskink I've already used default notification. but Popup notification (kind of Alert dialog with message) is another option for messengers.

Comment: would you like a `Service` that shows some disturbing popups all the time when you are for example browsing your favorite web page? i wouldn't

Answer (score 0):

You can start a Transparent activity from your service which shows the dialog within itself.

First create the "transparent" activity and set its theme like this in the `Manifest`

```
<activity android:name=".MyPopUpActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Set the background of this activity to a transparent colour of your choice.

From your service, start this activity. Make sure to pass whatever data needed to show the Dialog.

Once the activity is launched, use a `DialogFragment` to show the dialog. Using `DialogFragment` is the recommended way to display dialogs in android.

I haven't tested this approach myself but I am pretty sure it will do the trick for you.

Let me know if it works for you